# Cursor não atualiza o Nivel (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

Boa noite,

estou fazendo um cursor que  atualize a coluna nível da tabela de escolas com as seguintes regras:
 a. Escolas com mais de três níveis de ensino são niveladas com a categoria A 
 b. Escolas com três níveis de ensino são niveladas com a categoria B 
 c. Escolas com dois níveis de ensino são niveladas com a categoria C 
 d. Demais escolas são niveladas com a categoria D

O cursor tá colocando o resultado da Coluna Nivel como categoria 'C' em todas linhas, quero pegar o resultado do meu SELECT e usar ele pra adicionar as categorias na coluna Nivel,  segue o código até agora:

```
-- Variáveis do Cursor
DECLARE @Nivel CHAR(1),
        @CodigoNivelEnsino INT,
        @Contador INT= 0;

-- Cursor que atualiza a coluna nível da tabela de escolas.

DECLARE cur_AttTbNivel CURSOR FOR
SELECT CodigoNivelEnsino,count(CodigoNivelEnsino) AS 'Quantidade de Escolas por Nivel de Ensino'
FROM Escola_NivelEnsino 
GROUP BY CodigoNivelEnsino
HAVING COUNT(CodigoNivelEnsino) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(CodigoNivelEnsino) DESC

SELECT Nivel
FROM Escola

--Abrindo o cursor
OPEN cur_AttTbNivel;

-- Selecionar dados
FETCH NEXT FROM cur_AttTbNivel
INTO @Nivel, @CodigoNivelEnsino
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF @CodigoNivelEnsino >3
    UPDATE Escola
    SET Nivel = 'A'
    IF @CodigoNivelEnsino = 3
    UPDATE Escola
    SET Nivel = 'B'
    IF @CodigoNivelEnsino = 2
    UPDATE Escola
    SET Nivel = 'C'
    ELSE
    UPDATE Escola
    SET Nivel = 'D'



    WHERE
        Nivel = @Nivel



    FETCH NEXT FROM cur_AttTbNivel INTO @Nivel, @CodigoNivelEnsino;
END

-- Fechando e desalocando o cursor da memória
CLOSE cur_AttTbNivel
DEALLOCATE cur_AttTbNivel
```

Dados das Tabelas em questão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia Lucas.

Primeiramente peço por gentileza sempre dar o máximo de informações de código formatados como código (como criação das tabelas e insert das tabelas [que estavam em imagem])

Tive que deduzir/criar alguns nomes de campos para reproduzir seu problema.

Agora sobre o problema do seu cursor os problemas estavam em:

- Where - veja que seu where está somente na ultima condição, no else.
- If, elseif e else - A estrutura está incorreta fazendo que sempre caia no else no final pois não usou elseif
- Dados chave no Cursor - Veja que você não esta amarrando a escola que quer fazer o update.

Utilizei as seguintes tabelas e dados:

```
create table NivelEnsino
(
CodigoNivelEnsino int identity(1,1)
,nomenivel varchar(60)
)

create table escola
(
idescola int identity(1,1)
,nomeescola varchar(60)
,nivel char(2)
)

create table escola_nivelensino 
(
idescola int
,CodigoNivelEnsino int
)

insert into nivelensino 
select 'ensino fundamental' 
union
select 'ensino medio' 
union
select 'ensino tecnico' 
union
select 'ensino superior' 

insert into escola
select 'FAQ1 - 74','1'
union
select 'FAQI - POA','4'
union
select 'QI - ALVORADA','3'
union
select 'Escolinha do professor raimundo','10'
union
select 'escola do rock','7'

insert into escola_nivelensino
select 1,3
union
select 2,3
union
select 2,4
union
select 3,1
union
select 3,2
union
select 3,3
union
select 4,1
union
select 4,2
union
select 4,3
union
select 5,1
union
select 5,2
union
select 5,3
union
select 5,4
```

e o cursor ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
-- Variáveis do Cursor
DECLARE @idescola int,
        @CodigoNivelEnsino char(2)

-- Cursor que atualiza a coluna nível da tabela de escolas.
DECLARE cur_AttTbNivel CURSOR FOR
SELECT idescola
,count(CodigoNivelEnsino) AS 'Quantidade de nivel por escola'
FROM Escola_NivelEnsino 
GROUP BY idescola
ORDER BY COUNT(CodigoNivelEnsino) DESC

--Abrindo o cursor
OPEN cur_AttTbNivel;

-- Selecionar dados
FETCH NEXT FROM cur_AttTbNivel
INTO @idescola, @CodigoNivelEnsino
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF @CodigoNivelEnsino >3
        begin
            UPDATE Escola
            SET Nivel = 'A'
            where idescola = @idescola
        end 
    Else IF @CodigoNivelEnsino = 3
        begin
            UPDATE Escola
            SET Nivel = 'B'
            where idescola = @idescola
        end
    Else IF @CodigoNivelEnsino = 2
        begin
            UPDATE Escola
            SET Nivel = 'C'
            where idescola = @idescola
        end
    ELSE
        begin
            UPDATE Escola
            SET Nivel = 'D'
            WHERE idescola = @idescola
        end


    FETCH NEXT FROM cur_AttTbNivel INTO @idescola, @CodigoNivelEnsino;
END

-- Fechando e desalocando o cursor da memória
CLOSE cur_AttTbNivel
DEALLOCATE cur_AttTbNivel
```

Espero ter ajudado ;)